# Fatal error: Out of memory after install module via composer

Tags: magento2

I try to install payment module from GitHub.

https://github.com/dotpay/magento2-payment

When I run first command:

```
composer require dotpay/magento2-payment
```

Then I get error:

```
Using version ^1.0 for dotpay/magento2-payment

    ./composer.json has been updated
    Loading composer repositorUpdating dependencies (including require-dev)                                                                                                                      
    mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

    mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
    PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 553656320) (tried to allocate 4096 by                                                                                                             tes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.ph                                                                                                             p on line 220

    Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 553656320) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)                                                                                                              in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on                                                                                                              line 220
```

Anyone know how to solve it?

EDIT:
In php.ini I increased memory_limit to 2GB and 3GB.
[image]

Then I restart apache server (debian 9):
[image]

again try to install and still error:
[image]

EDIT2:

```
fsg@gerris:~/domains/aron.pl/public_html$ which php
```

**/usr/local/bin/php**

```
fsg@gerris:~/domains/aron.pl/public_html$ which composer
```

**/usr/local/bin/composer**

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase you php memory limit.

**To increase your PHP memory limit:**

1. Log in to your Magento server.
2. Locate your php.ini file using the following command: **php --ini**
3. As a user with root privileges, use a text editor to open the php.ini specified by Loaded Configuration File.
4. Locate memory_limit.
5. Change it to a value of 2GB for normal use and debugging.
6. Save your changes to php.ini and exit the text editor.
7. Restart your web server.

*Examples follow*:

> CentOS: service httpd restart
>
> Ubuntu: service apache2 restart
>
> nginx (both CentOS and Ubuntu): service nginx restart

Try the installation again.

Comment: I have 1024m, is it too small? memory_limit = 1024M

Comment: It is recommended to increase it to 2GB for debugging and major installations. Remember to restart your web server.

Comment: I gave you vote  because I know it should work but it does not work for me. I do not know why ! I updated my topic.

Comment: Dziekuje ;) Did you restart your web server after making those changes? Oh you did restart it... hymmm .... it don't look like it read it. What happens when you run put a full path to your php binary and also full path to where composer is installed?

Comment: @ Bare  Feet :)))  What do you mean "What happens when you run put a full path to your php binary and also full path to where composer is installed" very often it installs other modules through composer and everything works fine.

Comment: execute: "which php" and it should give you a full path to a binary, add that to your command instead of plain "php", note that you will need to specify the path to your composer too os type in "which composer" and it should give a path too.

Comment: I have update my topic with path "which composer" and "which php"

Comment: Try to run: /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer require dotpay/magento2-payment in ssh. Also, check default php by running: php -i

Comment: Did you manage to get anywhere with it?

Answer (score 0):

@Sylvester Please try this it may help you

```
which composer
```

it give you your composer location like mine `/usr/local/bin/composer`

then run this command

```
php -dmemory_limit=4G /usr/local/bin/composer require dotpay/magento2-payment
```

in my case dmemory_limit=4G You may try 2G